Why doesn't NSDateFormatter work as expected?
I've gotten some really strange results from the date formatter:
let testDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 725840000.0)
print(testDate)
2024-01-01 22:13:20 +0000
let fmt = DateFormatter()
fmt.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "America/Los_Angeles")
fmt.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
print(fmt.string(from: testDate))
14:13 //where's the am/pm, as specified?
fmt.dateFormat = "h:mm a z"
print(fmt.string(from: testDate))
14:13 PM PST //14:13 PM is just wrong!

Several questions arise:

Why is the am/pm in the format only results in output in conjunction with a timezone, not by itself?
Why would there ever be a situation when a 24 hour time is printed alongside am/pm, and why does it happen here despite the format indicating 12-hour time?
What actual format should I use to get what I want (2:13 PM in this case)? This doc: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns says h:mm a is correct, and it's linked to from Apple's docs, so is this a mismatch between docs and implementation?


This is affected by fmt.locale. Does the system locale use 24-hour or 12-hour clock?

My test code displays the AM/PM when using "h:mm a" and
also displays the timezone when using "h:mm a z".
You can use fmt.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") for example,
to override your Locale settings. Note re your question, you are using DateFormatter not NSDateFormatter.

i faced same problem when i wanted to get the 12H Time despite device is 24 or  12
that how i achieved it
let fullDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 725840000.0)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss" // first u format as 24h time
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // this important
    var time  = fullDate.description.components(separatedBy: " ")[1]
    let time24 = dateFormatter.date(from: time) // get the 24h time
    //now convert to 12H time
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    time = dateFormatter.string(from: time24!)

